# php: Looping wrong mysqli array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that connects successfully to a MySQL database and contains two mysqli queries.  The first query runs as expected.  The second query will only echo: **33111111**  I think I need to `free()` something, but I'm not sure what and I have tried to free the first result.

I am sure this is a simple mistake on my part. I appreciate your help!

pffages:

```
aid | aTitle | aActive | aVersion
---------------------------------
3   | 16-17  | 1       | 1       
4   | 14-15  | 1       | 1
5   | 15-16  | 1       | 1
```

pffchecklist (works fine with php):

```
lid | lTitle | lText | aid | cid
--------------------------------
1   | Check1 | hi    | 3   | 1
2   | Check2 | world | 4   | 1
```

ulist.php:

```
<?php
include('connections/conn.php');

$getList = $_GET['lid'];

$testsql = 'SELECT * FROM pffchecklist where lid=' . $getList . ';';
$testresult = mysqli_query($conn, $testsql);
$getrow = mysqli_fetch_array($testresult);

echo $getrow["lTitle"]; //works
echo $getrow['lText']; // works 

$getAgesSql = 'SELECT * FROM pffages where aActive = 1;';
$getAgesResult = mysqli_query($conn,$getAgesSql);
$getAges = mysqli_fetch_array($getAgesResult);
foreach($getAges as $theAges){
    echo $theAges['aTitle']; // returns 33111111
    echo $theAges['aid']; // returns 33111111
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$getages` is an array returned by myqli_fetch_array. That will be a one dimensional array, with *scalar* values. To see what that contains (for debugging) we can use `var_dump`

```
$getAges = mysqli_fetch_array($getAgesResult);

-- for debugging, show what is returned
var_dump($getAges);

-- show the values returned for the 'aTitle' and 'aid' columns 
echo $getAges['aTitle'];
echo $getAges['aid'];
```

I suspect that is what we are after.

---

It is possible to use a `foreach` loop to access the contents of the array. For example:

```
-- this displays the values in the array but not the key
foreach($getAges as $theAges) {
   echo $theAges;
}
```

With the default MYSQLI_BOTH, we're going to get two copies of each value. One set with numeric indexes, the other set with the column names

```
-- this will show the key along with the value
foreach($getAges as $key => $val) {
   echo "{$key} => {$val} ";
}
```

**FOLLOWUP**

"So, I need it to return the values of aid and aTitle -- 4 records. How do I fix this to do this?"

I'd do it like this. Specification is for "four records", we take that to mean "four rows"... if that's the upper limit of the number of rows we want to display, we can add a `LIMIT 4` clause to the query to avoid returning more than four rows. We can also add an ORDER BY clause so that the query is more deterministic, rather than MySQL returning rows in any order.

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.aid, p.aTitle FROM pffages p WHERE p.aActive = 1 ORDER BY p.aid LIMIT 4';
```

We'll stick with the procedural style, given that's what's used in the original code. This is how I would do it:

```
if(!$sth = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
   // error occurred
   die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
$i = 0;
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
   $i++;
   echo "row=" . $i . " aid=" . $row['aid'] . " aTitle=" . $row['aTitle'] . "\n";
}
```

(The usage of the `$i` is just as demonstration: counting the number of rows fetched. The number of times through the loop. References to `$i` could be removed, they aren't actually needed.)

```
if(!$sth = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
   die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
   echo "aid=" . $row['aid'] . " aTitle=" . $row['aTitle'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: var_dump returned array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["aid"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(5) "16-17" ["aTitle"]=> string(5) "16-17" [2]=> string(1) "1" ["aActive"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" ["aVersion"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: So `mysqli_fetch_array` is returning an array, as we expect. From the contents of the array, we can see that the query is returning four columns: (aid, aTitle, aActive, aVersion). And the values returned for the first row are ('3','16-17','1','1'). Because MYSQLI_BOTH is the default mode for mysqli_fetch_array, we're getting two copies of each column, so a total of eight elements in the returned array.

Comment: So, I need it to return the values of aid and aTitle -- 4 records.  How do I fix this to do this?

Comment: Added FOLLOWUP demonstrating "while fetch" loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('connections/conn.php');

$getList = $_GET['lid'];

$testsql = 'SELECT * FROM pffchecklist where lid=' . $getList . ';';
$testresult = mysqli_query($conn, $testsql);
$getrow = mysqli_fetch_array($testresult, MYSQLI_BOTH);

echo $getrow["lTitle"]; //works
echo $getrow['lText']; // works 

$getAgesSql = 'SELECT * FROM pffages where aActive = 1;';
$getAgesResult = mysqli_query($conn,$getAgesSql);
while( $getAge = mysqli_fetch_array($getAgesResult, MYSQLI_BOTH) ){
    $getAges[] = $getAge;
}
foreach($getAges as $theAges){
    echo $theAges['aTitle']; // returns 33111111
    echo $theAges['aid']; // returns 33111111
}
?>
```

Comment: Same result... 33111111

Answer (score 0):

```
$testsql = 'SELECT * FROM pffages order by aTitle;';
$testresult = mysqli_query($conn, $testsql);

while($testrow = mysqli_fetch_array($testresult)){
    echo $testrow['aTitle'];
}
```